# Windows file content indexation via script

Tags: batch-file, script, search-indexing, ps1

I just came across via the following command, but it won't enable Windows file content indexation, as you know this feature allows you to use search to look inside files and see the content of it.

So following CMD command doesn't do the trick:

`sc config "wsearch" start=delayed-auto && sc start "wsearch"`

I was wondering if there is any CMD or PS1 solution that would allow you to enable 'Index properties and file contents'

[Iamge of the window that enable this feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlkIp.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027486/how-to-script-configuring-windows-10-indexing

Comment: This is useful as well, but it doesn't turn on second option, it only adds extensions if the feature is already turned on

Comment: What is the second option? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc enabling 'Index Properties and File Contents', just like in the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlkIp.png
I wanted to know if there is any script solution that can tick that radio button with a single mouse click

Comment: Might help : https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/58569-rebuild-search-index-windows-10-a.html